# SQL print line number in comment of dynamically created stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, line-numbers

I have written a script that is several thousands of lines long that I am using to generate some stored procedures dynamically.

I want to reference the script that generated the stored procedures in the comments in the stored procedures, and would like to be able to refer to the line in the script file by inserting the line number of the script file into the comments in the stored procedure file.

So for example if @@line_number gave the line number I want in the code bellow then @@line_number should be 5

```
1| declare @job varchar(max)
2| SET @job = '/* this is generated dynamicly by _______  */'
3| SET @job = @job + 'SELECT *' + CHAR(10)
4| SET @job = @job + 'FROM ' + @Table_Name + CHAR(10)
5| SET @job = @job + '/* ' + @@line_number + ' */'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use line numbers as they will change over time as the script is updated. When that happens, the line number in the generated code will no longer point to the line number that it did at the time it was generated. Not a big deal if off by 1 or 2 but if you add a section then off by 20 or 30 could lead to confusion. Why not use "labels" like "Section 1" / "Section 2, Part 5" or something unique enough to search for and be found once.

Comment: The main script I am writing does a lot of stuff that is very similar so I am doing a lot of copy and past and then change a few thing and have tricked my self into searching for bug in the wrong place a few time because I have searched for a heading or comment that had been copied with the code, or because I have labeled to things the same. I have the script deleting all previously generated scripts and regenerating everything every time it runs so if I can put in the line number it should always be updated when there is any change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use TRY / CATCH with a forced error as the CATCH block can return the line number that the error occurred on via the ERROR_LINE() function.  The full construct, formatted for readability, is:

```
BEGIN TRY
    ;THROW 50000, 'Line#', 1 -- all 3 values are arbitrary, but required
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @LineNumber = ERROR_LINE()
END CATCH
```

Now, to get the @LineNumber variable to populate with the line number that it is being set on, you can reduce that construct to a single line as follows:

```
BEGIN TRY;THROW 50000,'',1;END TRY BEGIN CATCH;SET @Line=ERROR_LINE();END CATCH
```

Here is a full example of it working:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
-- Line #1 (of current batch, not of the entire script if GOs are used)

DECLARE @CRLF NCHAR(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', -- Line #5
        @Line INT = -1 -- default to an invalid line #

SET @SQL1 += N'/********************' + @CRLF
SET @SQL1 += N' *' + @CRLF
SET @SQL1 += N' * Test Auto-' + @CRLF -- Line #10
SET @SQL1 += N' * Generated Proc 1' + @CRLF
BEGIN TRY;THROW 50000,'',1;END TRY BEGIN CATCH;SET @Line=ERROR_LINE();END CATCH
SET @SQL1 += N' * Line #:' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Line) + @CRLF
SET @SQL1 += N' *' + @CRLF
SET @SQL1 += N' ********************/' + @CRLF -- Line #15

-- more code here

SET @SQL2 += N'/********************' + @CRLF
SET @SQL2 += N' *' + @CRLF -- Line #20
SET @SQL2 += N' * Test Auto-' + @CRLF
SET @SQL2 += N' * Generated Proc 2' + @CRLF
BEGIN TRY;THROW 50000,'',1;END TRY BEGIN CATCH;SET @Line=ERROR_LINE();END CATCH
SET @SQL2 += N' * Line #:' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Line) + @CRLF
SET @SQL2 += N' *' + @CRLF -- Line #25
SET @SQL2 += N' ********************/' + @CRLF

PRINT @SQL1
PRINT @SQL2
GO
```

The line numbers returned for Proc 1 and Proc 2 are 12 and 23 respectively, which is correct for both.

Please note that the THROW command started in SQL Server 2012. If you are using SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2, then you need to use RAISERROR() function instead of THROW.

Comment: Really would wish for a `@@LINE` or `LINE()`

Answer (score 1):

I changed [SolomonRutzky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19916706/577765) a bit to get is to work in SQL Server versions prior to 2012:

```
DECLARE @Line INT
SET @Line = 0 BEGIN TRY RAISERROR ('Line#', 11, 1)WITH NOWAIT   END TRY BEGIN CATCH SET @Line=ERROR_LINE() END CATCH

PRINT('/* testing ... I messed up somewhere near line: ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), ISNULL(@Line, 0)) + ' */')
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a built in function to return the current line number so I have started making a function to find the line number for me.

If I get the text of the current running query at the top and declare some variable, and then copy and past the function call and the @LineCounter increment code, I can get the current line number.

```
    DECLARE @var1 NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    SELECT @var1 = sqltext.TEXT
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
    WHERE req.session_id = @@SPID
    DECLARE @LineCounter int
    SET @LineCounter = 0
    DECLARE @Current_Line_Number int
    SET @Current_Line_Number = 0
SET @LineCounter = @LineCounter + 1
SELECT @Current_Line_Number = [MSMS].[dbo].[ReturnLineNumber] (@var1, @LineCounter)
PRINT @Current_Line_Number
```

This is the function

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      James J
-- Create date: 11/11/2013
-- Description: Function to return the line number for 
-- where the query was called from when passed the query 
-- an the count of the times it has already been used.
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION ReturnLineNumber 
(
    @CurrentQuery nvarchar(max), 
    @Count  int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var1 NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @functionName nvarchar(30)
    SET @functionName = 'ReturnLineNumber'
    SET @var1 = @CurrentQuery

    DECLARE @LineCount int
    SET @LineCount = 0

    IF (CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @var1) > 0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @queryString nvarchar(max)
        SET @queryString = @var1
        DECLARE @LineIndex int
        SET @LineIndex = 1
        DECLARE @LineLength int
        DECLARE @linestring nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE @functioncount int
        SET @functioncount = 0
        WHILE (@LineIndex > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @LineIndex = CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @queryString)
            SET @LineLength = LEN(@queryString) - CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @queryString)
            SET @linestring = SUBSTRING(@queryString, 0, @LineIndex + 1)
            SET @queryString = SUBSTRING(@queryString, @LineIndex + 1, @LineLength)
            SET @LineCount = @LineCount + 1
            IF (CHARINDEX(@functionName, @linestring) > 0)
            BEGIN
                SET @functioncount = @functioncount + 1
                IF (@functioncount = @Count)
                BEGIN
                    RETURN @LineCount
                END
            END
        END
    END
    RETURN 0
END
GO
```

This is not a great way to get the line number and I probably should add some more checks to make sure I don't have commented out function calls but this is the closest I have got for the moment.

Comment: need to do more testing with this because it is still giving errors